# remove old drive from Time Machine backup

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine

My old HDD died, I restored data to a new one, but now I have two versions of backup: new and old
The name was MyVolume, in Time Machine I have now MyVolume and MyVolume1

I already tried `tmutil addexclusion` and exclusions in Time Machine options
I tried to rename my new HDD, tried to use another empty HDD with the same name
but this old backup is still there

How can I remove one of it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in this answer:
[How can I delete Time Machine files using the commandline](https://superuser.com/questions/162690/how-can-i-delete-time-machine-files-using-the-commandline)

I used `/System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass`
and it worked for me